# node-spider wait for lazy-load content

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I am using NodeJS' `node-spider` to crawl website content, but it came with a problem is it won't wait for lazyload content to be loaded before grab the page content, especially like Angular kind of page which implement lazyload a lot.

I'm new to spider/crawler technology, not sure what is the configuration need to be done or any better library to solve this issue.

My code is exactly same as the code sample from the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-spider